# What is the volume of a parallelotope knowing its heights?

Tags: geometry, volume

For a $d$ dimensional parallelotope, if all of its heights $h_1, \ldots, h_d$ are known, how do I express its volume?

Comment: $V=\prod\limits_{i=1}^d h_i$.

Comment: If the edges of the parallelotope are mutually perpendicular, then the answer in the comment of @DavidG.Stork is correct. If, on the other hand, the angles are arbitrary and if "height" means the distance between two parallel faces (measured along a line perpendicular to those faces), then the heights are not sufficient information to determine the volume, not even in the two-dimensional case.